# How can I count column 2 with other column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID , COUNT(T2.OPT_ID) 
FROM TABLE1 , TABLE2
WHERE T1.TRACK_ID = T2.TRACK_ID
GROUP BY T1.ID, T2.OPT_ID
```

Output:

```
ID (COLUMN1)        OPT_ID(COLUMN 2)
1000000001082157827 132665
1000000001082157827 132564
1000000001082157827 117345
1000000001082157827 11565
1000000001082157827 124546
1000000001082157827 117495
1000000001082157827 11564
1000000001082157827 11564
1000000001082157827 117495
```

If I count T2.OPT_ID it only count 1 per T1.ID but it's okay if i only count t2.opt_id but need these two columns.
result should look like this

```
ID (COLUMN1)        | OPT_ID(COLUMN 2)
000000001082157827  | 7
```

There also some case that OPT_ID have two same id. I should get same total number (7 not 9)

Comment: try to remove `T2.OPT_ID` from `group by`

Comment: Updated answer in the comments section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.id,count(distinct t2.opt_id) 
from table1,tabel2 
where t1.track_id=t2.track_id 
group by t1.id
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: But there are some case where t2.opt_id appeared several time in  column.. Need to be distinct.. Do you have any solution?

Comment: i have edited my answer... all you need is to count distinct of that column

Answer (score 1):

For the current dataset the below query should give you the result

```
SELECT T1.ID , COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.TRACK_ID = T2.TRACK_ID 
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

In the given example, you dont have a table2, I am not sure how table2 influences the result set. If you are using `group by` for any particular column, you need not give `distinct` for that column again. Both serves the same purpose (`Group by` is preferred over `distinct` when performance is considered).

Comment: But there are some case where t2.opt_id appeared several time in column.. Need to be distinct.. Do you have any solution?

Comment: `SELECT T1.ID , COUNT(DISTINCT T2.OPT_ID) 
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.TRACK_ID = T2.TRACK_ID 
GROUP BY T1.ID`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following query:

```
SELECT id ,(SELECT Sum(Count(*))
 FROM t12 GROUP BY opt_id HAVING Count(*)=1) AS count1
 FROM t12---change the table name
 GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: This will get the result as expected